# meteor application: how to get access log / error log like Apache server?

Tags: meteor

is it possible to see access log / and Apache log as we see for Apache server to check what going with meteor server. ? can i look it as a domain or as a whole servers?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) to deploy your applications into your own server (which I recommend and should save you a lot of time on the long run), you can access your logs at: `/var/log/upstart/app.log`.

This will even allow you to tail logs from the server in your local application directory by running:

```
mup logs -f  # it supports all the options of tail
```

Also, if you want to reset your logs:

```
cd /var/log/upstart/
sudo cat /dev/null > app.log
```

Answer (score 0):

well, depends on how fancy you want to go, it could be as simple as:

`meteor > /var/log/meteor.log`

it redirect the output to `/var/log/meteor.log`

if that doesnt float your boat, there are a bunch of packages pre-made for that, of which this one looks like the most flexible:
https://atmospherejs.com/package/trail